# How can I enter a Kubernetes managed container faster?

Tags: kubernetes

Currently if I'm about to inspect my container, I have to do three steps:

1. kubectl get all -n {NameSpace}
2. kubectl describe {Podname from step 1} -n {NameSpace}
3. Find the Node Host and the container ID (My eyes are complaning!)
4. Switch to the host and execute "docker exec -ti -u root {Container ID} bash"

I am so mad about it right now. Wish somebody could offer some help to me and those who may share the same issue.

Comment: `kubectl exec -it somepod -- bash`

Comment: @steve Wu :  Lei Yang commad will work. just adding the link to  kubernetes documentation on connection to container shell . Link  : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Pods are the smallest deployable units of computing that you can
> create and manage in Kubernetes.

So, if you want to "enter" a container, you just need to "exec" into the pod in a particular namespace. Kubernetes will get you the shell/command for that pod.

```
kubectl -n somenamespace exec -it podname -- bash
```

There is no need to mention the node here as Kubernetes internally knows on which node the pod is scheduled.

> If a Pod has more than one container, use --container or -c to specify
> a container in the kubectl exec command. For example, suppose you have
> a Pod named my-pod, and the Pod has two containers named main-app and
> helper-app. The following command would open a shell to the main-app
> container.

```
kubectl exec -it my-pod -c main-app -- /bin/bash
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/

Comment: sometimes `bash` is not available in the container and `sh` may be needed.

Comment: @P....   Agree. I used bash  because thats what OP is using in his containers.